# Time series monthly incidence

Tags: r

I want to do a time series plot about the incidence by year or month, now I have the daily data, how can I change the daily plot to monthly plot or year plot?

I have the data from Jan 1st 2013 to Dec 31st 2017, sample data like this:

```
dput(head(Incidence_byday,n=20))

structure(list(DATE = structure(c(15706, 15707, 15708, 15709, 15710, 15711, 15712, 
                                      15713, 15714, 15715, 15716, 15717, 15718, 15719, 
                                      15720, 15721, 15722, 15723, 15724, 15725), 
                                    class = "Date"), 
                   Inpatient = c(5L, 7L, 3L, 52L, 111L, 150L, 177L, 251L, 292L, 321L, 338L, 
                                 178L, 124L, 346L, 368L, 354L, 375L, 461L, 220L, 148L), 
                   HAI = c(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 10, 8, 13, 9, 0, 12, 10, 11, 11, 15, 10, 7, 8), 
                   Incidence = c(0, 0, 0, 7.69230769230769, 0.900900900900901, 0.666666666666667, 
                                 1.69491525423729, 3.98406374501992, 2.73972602739726, 
                                 4.04984423676012, 2.66272189349112, 0, 9.67741935483871, 
                                 2.89017341040462, 2.98913043478261, 3.10734463276836, 
                                 4, 2.16919739696312, 3.18181818181818, 5.40540540540541)), 
              row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
#install.packages("ggplot2")
#install.packages("lubridate")

library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(Incidence_byday, aes(x=DATE)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Incidence)) + 
  labs(title="Incidence trend", y="Incidence %")
```

The result like this:
[image]

Comment: Don't add data as a picture. Use dput. read [help\mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To get the incidence rate over other time periods, you can use `lubridate` to assign each DATE to a particular week, month, or year, and then `group_by` + `summarize` & `mutate` to get stats over that time period:

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
Incidence_byweek <- Incidence_byday %>%
  group_by(DATE = floor_date(DATE, "7 days")) %>% # e.g., or "1 month" or "1 year"
  summarize(Inpatient = sum(Inpatient),
            HAI = sum(HAI)) %>%
  mutate(Incidence = 100 * HAI / Inpatient)
```

Then plot with the new data: (in this case by week since the original data was all in one month and year)

```
ggplot(Incidence_byweek, aes(x=DATE)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Incidence)) + 
  labs(title="Incidence trend", y="Incidence %")
```

[image]